# How to say that research work was done as part of research project?

Tags: publications, thesis

I'm carrying out a research work as part of a big research project. How to mention this in the abstract for an article?

The best I can is "This research work was conducted as part of the project #xxxx-xx", but I believe there's well-known phrase to replace "as part of".

Comment: The precise wording really doesn't matter, as long as the acknowledgement is clear and unambiguous.  "As part of" is fine.

Comment: Check with the administrator of the project at your local institution. There may be an expected way to write this for a given funding source. If so, use it!

Comment: Typically, at least in fields that I am familiar with, for articles this type of thing goes in the acknowledgments and not the abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to address comments.**

If Project XYZ is simply a funding agency or entity that may have provided funds or materials but no intellectual contribution, then you use the phrase "We acknowledge Agency XYZ (Grant #) for financial support" or "Funding provided through Project XYZ (Grant #)." For example, if your work is supported by a grant from the National Institutes of Health...

> "Funding for this work was provided by the NIH, Center for Work on Really Interesting Science (#1234567890)..."

If project XYZ has defined the research problem/scope, you could say "This research was inspired by Project XYZ" or "This research follows from Porject XYZ."

If Project XYZ is an institute, center, or other entity that worked with you on your project, then you use the phase "in collaboration with". For example, if your computational model was run on at the [Pittsburgh Supercomputing Center](http://www.psc.edu/), you might say:

> "This work was conducted in collaboration with the Pittsburgh Supercomputing Center [ref]..."

Lastly, if the intellectual contribution from someone at Project XYZ was large, that person needs to have their name on your paper (with placement in the order according to the customs of your field):

Grad Student who did the work*, Grad Student who did less work*, Grad Student at Project XYZ<sup>#</sup>, Collaborating PI at Project XYZ<sup>#</sup>, Your PI*

Affiliations:

```
*Department of Epic Awesome, University of Cool, 123 Street Road, CityTown,
 ProvinceState, CountryNation, ComplicatedPostalCode.
#Center for Statistical Mayhem, International Project for 
 Enhancing Statistical Literacy through Academic Research, 456 Boulevard Ave,
 CityTown, ProvinceState, CountryNation, ComplicatedPostalCode.
```

Comment: The project in this context is not a supporting entity, but rather an organizing entity: the key research directions are defined within a project and my work concerns one of those. How to reflect this in an acknowledgement?

Comment: @starteleport - also, Project XYZ may have a standard attribution line that they would like you to use in your acknowledgements. Contact them.